# not reading a numeric value using input list method in sas

Tags: sas

This is the story

This is the input file

```
mukesh,04/04/15,04/06/15,125.00,333.23
vishant,04/05/15,04/07/15,200.00,200
achal,04/06/15,04/08/15,275.00,55.43
```

this is the import statement that I am using

```
data datetimedata;
infile fileref dlm=','; 
input lastname$  datechkin mmddyy10. datechkout mmddyy10. room_rate equip_cost;
run;
```

the below is the log which shows success

```
NOTE: The infile FILEREF is:
      Filename=\\VBOXSVR\win_7\SAS\DATA\datetime\datetimedata.csv,
      RECFM=V,LRECL=256,File Size (bytes)=688,
      Last Modified=13Jun2015:12:08:36,
      Create Time=13Jun2015:09:13:09

NOTE: 17 records were read from the infile FILEREF.
      The minimum record length was 34.
      The maximum record length was 40.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DATETIMEDATA has 17 observations and 5 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
```

I have published only 3 observation here.

**Now when I print the sas dataset everything works fine except the *room_rate* variable.**

[image: output of proc print]

THe output should be 3 digit numbers , but i am getting only the last digit . 
Where Am i going wrong !!!

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing input types.  When you use list input, you can't specify informats.  You either need to specify them using modified list input (add a colon to the informat) or use an `informat` statement earlier.  The following works.

```
data datetimedata;
infile datalines dlm=','; 
input lastname$  datechkin :mmddyy10. datechkout :mmddyy10. room_rate equip_cost;
datalines;
mukesh,04/04/15,04/06/15,125.00,333.23
vishant,04/05/15,04/07/15,200.00,200
achal,04/06/15,04/08/15,275.00,55.43
;;;;
run;

proc print data=datetimedata;
run;
```

Comment: data datetimedata;
infile fileref dlm=',' firstobs=1; 
input lastname$  datechkin :mmddyy10. datechkout :mmddyy10. room_rate equip_cost;
run; this worked for me . the difference is ':' before mmddyy10. I am a beginer. Would be great if you can explain me what is ':' doing here :D . Thanx

Comment: can you help me ? What is the use of ':' before ddmmyy10. That is making the difference in result.